# NuGet modal windows preventing user interaction with init.ps1 through the console

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-2013, nuget

A package has an `init.ps1` script which sometimes needs to ask the user for confirmation because it's actions may cause data loss.

I'm currently using `Read-Host` to ask for user input. It writes the message to "Package Manager Console" panel and waits for input via keyboard on the same panel.

The problem is NuGet for VS2013 use modal windows for everything, which prevent the user to type on the console while using NuGet GUIs.

Unless the script is triggered by opening the solution or installing the package through command line, the script will lock Visual Studio.

A confirmation dialog could be used instead of Read-Host, hoping the dialog will take precedence over NuGet windows, but this solution is suboptimal because mixing command line and GUI is disruptive.

I would like to display a dialog if the script was triggered by the GUI and prompt on the command line otherwise. Is it possible?

PS: I've noticed NuGet acts this way, but was unable to find the code responsible for this behavior on it's GitHub repo.